# Strange "error" when entering decimal values in if/else statement

Tags: java

I'm using Netbeans. New to programming, just started java today and have a question.

```
System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    double numberOne = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if (numberOne > 0) {
                System.out.println("The number " + numberOne + " is positive.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The number " + numberOne + " isn't positive.");
            }
```

Typing in whole numbers, whether positive or negative will display the right message. But if I enter something like .25 or 7.29, this will appear and neither messages are displayed:

```
Type a number: 
7.29
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.29"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at PositiveValue.main(PositiveValue.java:9)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

What can I do to make it work with decimals and maybe fractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `reader` is of type `Scanner`, then use [`Scanner#nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) instead to read the value as `double` and store it in your `double` variable.

After this, read the line to consume the line break character(s):

```
double numberOne = reader.nextDouble();
reader.nextLine();
```

For your other question:

> What can I do to make it work with (...) fractions?

You should create a proper class that will store your numerator and denominator, both of type `int` or `long`, this will depend on your design.

Comment: Thank you for the help, starting to realize more and more what people mean when they say there's so many ways to do one thing in java.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `double` variable and you are setting an `int` on it. You have to use [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) function, as follows:

```
double numberOne = Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
new Double(1.25)
```

instead of

```
new Integer(1.25)
```

to avoid these sorts of errors. Integers can only be whole numbers while Double values can be decimals.

In your case

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(reader.nextLine());
```

should give you the value you want.